# getting starting row and matching row, and continue till the end

Tags: sql

I have the following view:

```
+-------------+----------+--------+-----+
| PartitionBy | FirstDoc | EndDoc | Gap |
+-------------+----------+--------+-----+
| abc         |        1 |     10 |   0 |
| abc         |       11 |     30 |   0 |
| abc         |       31 |     34 |   2 |
| abc         |       37 |     40 |   0 |
| abc         |       41 |     50 |   3 |
| abc         |       54 |     60 |   0 |
| abc         |       61 |     70 |   0 |
| dce         |        2 |     10 |   0 |
| dce         |       11 |     15 |   2 |
| dce         |       18 |     20 |   0 |
| dce         |       21 |     30 |   2 |
| dce         |       33 |     40 |   0 |
+-------------+----------+--------+-----+
```

I am trying to get the start of FirstDoc to the last of EndDoc after a Gap is found. This is what i am trying to achieve:

```
+-------------+----------+--------+-----+
| PartitionBy | FirstDoc | EndDoc | Gap |
+-------------+----------+--------+-----+
| abc         |        1 |     34 |   2 |
| abc         |       37 |     50 |   3 |
| abc         |       54 |     70 |   0 |
| dce         |        2 |     15 |   2 |
| dce         |       18 |     30 |   2 |
| dce         |       33 |     40 |   0 |
+-------------+----------+--------+-----+
```

This is what i did,

```
 SELECT PartitionBy, FirstDoc, EndDoc, GAP,
 CASE
    WHEN GAP =0 THEN MIN(FirstDoc)
    WHEN GAP >0 THEN MAX(EndDoc) 
    END as Datum
    from testgaptable group by PartitionBy, FirstDoc, EndDoc,Gap;
```

It gives me following, where the datum do take the last when there is gap, however, i can't figure out how to chain it to give the first and last and keep on going for the same partition.

```
+-------------+----------+--------+------+-------+
| PartitionBy | FirstDoc | EndDoc | GAP  | Datum |
+-------------+----------+--------+------+-------+
| abc         |     1.00 |  10.00 | 0.00 |  1.00 |
| abc         |    11.00 |  30.00 | 0.00 | 11.00 |
| abc         |    31.00 |  34.00 | 2.00 | 34.00 |
| abc         |    37.00 |  40.00 | 0.00 | 37.00 |
| abc         |    41.00 |  50.00 | 3.00 | 50.00 |
| abc         |    54.00 |  60.00 | 0.00 | 54.00 |
| abc         |    61.00 |  70.00 | 0.00 | 61.00 |
| dce         |     2.00 |  10.00 | 0.00 |  2.00 |
| dce         |    11.00 |  15.00 | 2.00 | 15.00 |
| dce         |    18.00 |  20.00 | 0.00 | 18.00 |
| dce         |    21.00 |  30.00 | 2.00 | 30.00 |
| dce         |    33.00 |  40.00 | 0.00 | 33.00 |
+-------------+----------+--------+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your RDBM suppports `sum` as a `window function` you can create an artificial column in order to group by records between gaps.

```
with cte as (
select *
    ,case when gap = 0 then 
                        sum(case when gap > 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by PartitionBy order by FirstDoc asc)
          when gap > 0 then sum(case when gap > 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by PartitionBy order by FirstDoc asc) - 1
     end as invisible_grouping
from v )
select 
     PartitionBy
    ,min(FirstDoc) as FirstDoc
    ,max(EndDoc) as EndDoc
    ,max(gap) as gap
from cte
group by PartitionBy, invisible_grouping
order by PartitionBy, FirstDoc
```

Output from the `cte`:

```
PartitionBy FirstDoc    EndDoc  Gap invisible_grouping
abc              1        10    0           0
abc              11       30    0           0
abc              31       34    2           0
abc              37       40    0           1
abc              41       50    3           1
abc              54       60    0           2
abc              61       70    0           2
dce              2        10    0           0
dce              11       15    2           0
dce              18       20    0           1
dce              21       30    2           1
dce              33       40    0           2
```

I created an additional column (`invisible_grouping`) that has the same value for rows that you want to merge into one row. Then I used this column in `group by`, but not in the `select`.
The final output:

```
PartitionBy FirstDoc    EndDoc  gap
abc             1          34   2
abc             37         50   3
abc             54         70   0
dce             2          15   2
dce             18         30   2
dce             33         40   0
```

Comment: Excellent. I will go through this in detail. Just the way i wanted to.